# SiriKit & Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, siri, sirikit

I'm interested in capabilities of the SiriKit. From what I found is that SiriKit supports messaging, VoIP, radio, payments etc.

I am curious, can SiriKit either approve my notification, read the content of it etc.?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean - your app posts a notification, user tells Siri to interact with it by using a keyword and the interaction continues?

Comment: @nambatee yes, I assume this kind of interaction